# Import existing repository to different GitHub Account

Tags: git, github

How can I import the existing repository with all comments from my Github account to someone else GitHub account?

Comment: look at this document from [docs.github.com/](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository#transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-user-account)

Comment: I know the transfer but I am looking for something like just import it. I mean I want to keep the repo with me and with a different account If I will transfer the repo to different accounts I can not keep the same repo on my real account.

Comment: Are you looking to [fork the repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo)?

Comment: Yeah , That's what I was looking it ! 
Thanks :)